# Псевдоэлемент ::before и :before

Tags: css, css3

В чем различие `::before` и `:before`? Или `::after` и `:after`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ранее с появлением `CSS2.1` синтаксис псевдоэлементов (напр. `:before`) и псевдоклассов (напр. `:first-child`) не отличался: оба варианта писались с двоеточием в качестве префикса, дабы указать на их псевдосущность.

С появлением `CSS3` товарищи из W3C решили указать на их отличие друг от друга, оставив одно двоеточие для псевдоклассов (`:not`), но введя двойное двоеточие для псевдоэлементов (`::before` и `::after`).

*P.S. Всеми любимый IE до версии 9.0 не поддерживает двойные двоеточия, так что надёжнее использовать по-прежнему одинарные, если разработка ведётся не только для современных браузеров.*

Подробнее про псевдоэлементы можно почитать по ссылке: [псевдоэлемент ::before](https://webref.ru/css/before)

Answer (score 6):

`:before`, как и `:after` оставлены для поддержки старых браузеров. **Разницы нет**.

> /* CSS3 синтаксис */
>
> `element::before { свойства }`
>
> /* CSS2 устаревший синтаксис (нужен только для поддержки IE8) */
>
> `element:before  { свойства }`
>
> *[Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

Comment: `:before`, как и `:after ` не были добавлены для поддержки старых браузеров, как раз наоборот в новых браузерах поддерживаются псевдоэлементы с двойным двоеточием, а одинарное двоеточие было изначально.

Comment: @lexxl сути это не меняет.